# 1 MB response size limit with outlook web add-ins

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm using makeEwsRequestAsync to get the full MIME content of the email. But it looks like response size is capped at 1 MB, per the error message in the response:
"ErrorMessage":"Response exceeds 1 MB size limit. Please modify your EWS request.”

```
<GetItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
  <ItemShape>
    <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
    <t:AdditionalProperties>
        <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:MimeContent"/>
    </t:AdditionalProperties>
  </ItemShape>
  <ItemIds><t:ItemId Id="' + itemId + '"/></ItemIds>
</GetItem>
```

I need to get MIME content of messages which may exceed 1 MB, and also POST such content to our server. Is there any way to increase this limit in the request, or configure this on the Exchange side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to make EWS requests to the client side that exceed 1 MB, however you can give your server the information that it needs to make the request itself.

You first need to call `Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync` which will give you a token you can use to make EWS requests from your server.

Then you will need to get the item ID which is available through `Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId`.

Finally, you need the url to make the request to, which is `Office.context.mailbox.ewsUrl`

With these 3 pieces of information, your server can make the SOAP call to EWS from your backend, and bypass the 1 MB limit imposed on the client. At this point, you can pass whatever information needed back to your client.

Comment: How can i get the complete MEssage (.msg Objekt) which is an enrichment of the MimeContent?

Comment: For reference, see [all limitations of the JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/limits-for-activation-and-javascript-api-for-outlook-add-ins)

Comment: Ran into the 1mb issue when trying to call ExpandDL with a DL that has 5k+ recipients. Tried the EWS token from `getCallbackTokenAsync ` to see if it would work before realizing the token is scoped to only allow access to the item in context (i.e. draft). Found a workaround using a utility account and authenticating via username/password. Might also going to explore paging the ExpandDL call too. Anyone have any other ideas?