# Rest POST query using multipart/Form-data

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I have a REST API that I will be accessing via JQuery in an Outlook AddIn for O365.  This particular Rest query requires multipart/form-data as part of the request.  In this case, I need this data to be the Outlook msg data and/or the email attachment.  The API knows what do with the data once it has it.  So the data has to be the .msg file and/or the email attachment which in this case could be PDF, TIFF, etc.

Is there an object in Outlook 365 that can be accessed (MSG and Attachment) to create a data object to pass to the rest call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no easy option for getting at the raw MIME content or file versions of emails and attachments. There are ways to do so with Exchange Web Services, but there are size limits that you can hit if your add-in is used on mobile devices and you also may require server-side processing.  See here for a similar discussion: [Office outlook web(AddIn) dowloand message file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44631907/office-outlook-webaddin-dowloand-message-file/53075275#53075275)