# Get MIME mail content in Outlook Addin via Graph

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to create an outlook addin, that reads the selected mail in .MSG or .EML format. I found a
[Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44631907/how-can-i-retrieve-the-full-mime-message-from-an-microsoft-outlook-add-in) with a link to this documentation how to read a mail from Graph: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message. I tried to use [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{id}/$value](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/%7Bid%7D/$value) with the [Graph tester](https://developer.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/graph-explorer). I entered all ids i could find in the `Office.context.mailbox.item` but none of them gave me a valid result. So where do I have to take the id from, the Graph Tester needs?

Comment: Try using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages` which gives the list of messages in your mailbox. Pick the id for which ever message you want MIME content for and then call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{id}/$value `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that: `Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId.replace('/', '-').replace('+', '_');` gets the same id, the graph gives when asking for all messages via `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages`. I just do not know why I have to replace chars in the id.

Comment: Your base64 value needs to be made Base64urlsafe which is what you doing with the replaces.