# Sending EWS GetItem request from outlook web addin with 'IncludeMimeContent' set to true

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I need to access the email message in `RFC5322` format from my Outlook Web Add-in and send it to my back-end.

The add-in needs to support on-premise Exchange servers as well. I tried sending a `GetItem` request with `IncludeMimeContent` set to true using the `makeEwsRequestAsync` API.

The response I get is what I need. But this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh545614(v=exchg.140).aspx) mentions `IncludeMimeContent` is expensive operation.

I am not expecting continuous and many concurrent `GetItem` requests to the Exchange server. There could be an occasional spike in no. of requests.

Can I go ahead with this approach? Would it have adverse impact on the exchange server?

Any other alternative approach that I can look into?

Answer (score 0):

One issue I would be concerned with would be the size limit eg there is a 1MB limit you should run into if a message has large attachments if you request the MIME content which would include the attachments. You might wan't to look at doing something like [1 MB response size limit with outlook web add-ins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489704/1-mb-response-size-limit-with-outlook-web-add-ins)